# Software tool to generate the Ising model for random $k$-SAT problems

Tags: statistical-physics, phase-transition, random-k-sat, max2sat

Is there a software tool available to study the phase transition of the underlying Ising model for a given class of random $k$-SAT problems? I am basically asking whether the framework presented in [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.56.1357) is already implemented in a public domain library.

Comment: I am not aware of open-source implementations for specifically the Ising model mapping of k-SAT, but here are a couple of suggestions that might be helpful. The first paper below explicitly constructs OR gates in terms of Ising spins. The second paper describes numerical techniques for solving Ising and other spin-glass problems using tensor networks, and includes an open-source implementation.

https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.1742
https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.03014